How can I go back to exact scroll position in WebView?
I am creating an app that uses Android WebView. However, when I use the function goBack() it does not take me to the exact scroll position. In addition, my page is dynamically loading. When I scroll down, more product is getting loaded and the page is getting taller. How can I go back to the exact scroll position when I goBack()?
I tried using stacks by storing URLs but it did not work. Also, I tried storing scroll position Y and restoring when I go back to previous page. However, my page is dynamically loading so it did not work either.
